# How to move rigidbody player to its facing direction with AddForce?

Tags: c#, unity, physics, movement

How can I move a rigidbody to its facing direction? I've already tried this:

```
rigidbody.AddForce (transform.forward * v, ForceMode.Acceleration);
// v is a public float which gets a new value in Update function:
v = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * Speed;
```

in FixedUpdate, but it doesn't move forward.
[image: Movement of the cylinder]
It should go on that blue arrow, but it spins on the red arrow.

Hopefully u understood. Any suggestions?

Comment: how about Vector3.forward ?

Comment: is your objekt able to turn on the red arrow axis or other axis? if it isn't use vector3.forward

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using AddForce use AddRelativeForce

```
    rigidbody.AddRelativeForce (transform.forward * v, ForceMode.Acceleration);

    v = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * Speed;
```

Answer (score 0):

My code works good.
For example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AddForce : MonoBehaviour {

public Rigidbody myBody;
public float ForcePower;
public Vector3 myDirection;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    myBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{

}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    myBody.AddForce(myDirection, ForceMode.Force);
}
```

}